# Capacitor discharging

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

We know that discharge a capacitor will cause the voltage of capacitor to drop with time. But how about the [bleeder resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeder_resistor)? Will the voltage of bleeder resistor increase or remain unchanged?

Comment: You might consider moving any further questions to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

The bleeder resistor is *across* the capacitor so they have identical voltage across.

Comment: Did you mean they are in parallel ?

Comment: @user208886, yes by *across the capacitor*, I mean in parallel with the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor is connected in parallel with the bleeder resistor. The voltage between the terminals of the capacitor is equal to the potential difference between the bleeder resistor.
So the volatage should......?